# input character limit and number range

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an input and I want only numbers to be entered in this input and also the value entered should be between 0 and 36.
I want to set a maximum of 2 characters, but I have no idea, can you help?

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="36" maxlength="2" v-model.number="hello">

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     hello:""
    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: This is determined with max and depends on browser implementation. If you need to make it more strict, modify hello in a watcher to fit the range

Answer (score 0):

You can create [`watcher`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) and check if entered value is lower then 0 or bigger then 36:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      hello: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    hello(newVal, oldVal) {
      if(!newVal) {
        this.hello = ''
        return
      } 
      this.hello = newVal < 1 || newVal > 35 ? oldVal : newVal
    }
  },
  methods: {
    check(e) {
      if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="number" v-model.number="hello" @keypress="check($event)">
</div>
```